# css accordion scroll to top of page with active panel

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

I use an CSS only Accordion Menu without JS.
But i have one Problem. When i open the sub-menu, my complete Website page scrolls automaticly down to this Menu button with the sub-menu i clicked and is not fixed. I want just that the sub-menu opens without scrolling my Page.
Theres an Solution?

Can be find [here](http://jsfiddle.net/omulet/GuvB4/2/)

Html

```
<ul class="accordion">

  <li id="one" class="files">
    <a href="#one">My Files<span>495</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#one"><em>01</em>Dropbox<span>42</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#one"><em>02</em>Skydrive<span>87</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#one"><em>03</em>FTP Server<span>366</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#one"><em>01</em>Dropbox<span>42</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#one"><em>01</em>Dropbox<span>42</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li id="two" class="mail">
    <a href="#two">Mail<span>26</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#two"><em>01</em>Hotmail<span>9</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#two"><em>02</em>Yahoo<span>14</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#two"><em>03</em>Gmail<span>3</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li id="three" class="cloud">
    <a href="#three">Cloud<span>58</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#three"><em>01</em>Connect<span>12</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#three"><em>02</em>Profiles<span>19</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#three"><em>03</em>Options<span>27</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li id="four" class="sign">
    <a href="#four">Sign Out</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#four"><em>01</em>Log Out</a></li>
      <li><a href="#four"><em>02</em>Delete Account</a></li>
      <li><a href="#four"><em>03</em>Freeze Account</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

CSS

```
body {margin:50px;}

/* Reset */
.accordion,
.accordion ul,
.accordion li,
.accordion a,
.accordion span {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
.accordion li {
  list-style: none;
}

/* Layout & Style */
.accordion li > a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 110px;
  padding: 0 10px 0 40px;
  height: 32px;

  color: #fdfdfd;
  font: bold 12px/32px Arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .35);

  background: #6c6e74;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%, #4b4d51 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#6c6e74), color-stop(100%,#4b4d51));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%,#4b4d51 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%,#4b4d51 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%,#4b4d51 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%,#4b4d51 100%);

  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}

.accordion > li:hover > a,
.accordion > li:target > a {
  color: #3e5706;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .2);

  /*background: url(../img/active.png) repeat-x;*/
  background: #a5cd4e;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%, #6b8f1a 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#a5cd4e), color-stop(100%,#6b8f1a));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%); 
}

.accordion li > a span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;

  font: normal bold 12px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #404247;

  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;

  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2), 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2), 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .1);
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2), 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .1);
}


.accordion > li:hover > a span,
.accordion > li:target > a span {
  color: #fdfdfd;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .35);
  background: #3e5706;
}

/* Images */

.accordion > li > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 4px 8px;

  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(http://designmodo.com/demo/css3accordionmenu/img/icons.png);
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.accordion li.files > a:before { background-position: 0px 0px; }
.accordion li.files:hover > a:before,
.accordion li.files:target > a:before { background-position: 0px -24px; }

.accordion li.mail > a:before { background-position: -24px 0px; }
.accordion li.mail:hover > a:before,
.accordion li.mail:target > a:before { background-position: -24px -24px; }

.accordion li.cloud > a:before { background-position: -48px 0px; }
.accordion li.cloud:hover > a:before,
.accordion li.cloud:target > a:before { background-position: -48px -24px; }

.accordion li.sign > a:before { background-position: -72px 0px; }
.accordion li.sign:hover > a:before,
.accordion li.sign:target > a:before { background-position: -72px -24px; }

/* Sub Menu */

.sub-menu li a {
  color: #797979;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .2);

  background: #e5e5e5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c9c9c9;

  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}

.sub-menu li:hover a { background: #efefef; }

.sub-menu li:last-child a { border: none; }

.sub-menu li > a span {
  color: #797979;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .2);
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;

  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.sub-menu em {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 14px;
  color: #a6a6a6;
  font: normal 10px/32px Arial, sans-serif;
}

/* Functionality */

.accordion li > .sub-menu li {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;

  -webkit-transition: height .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: height .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: height .2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: height .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: height .2s ease-in-out;
}

.accordion li:target > .sub-menu li {
  height: 33px;
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite understanding the problem.

Comment: Update your jsfiddle and add a couple of paragraphs under the accordion so people understand what the problem is. +1 for implementing all of this in pure CSS :O

Answer (score 0):

The jumping happens because of `href="#id"`

you have two options change the code to not require `href="#id"`

or

add this

```
$('.accordion a').click(function (e) {
    var x = window.pageXOffset,
        y = window.pageYOffset;
    $(window).one('scroll', function () {
        window.scrollTo(x, y);
    })
});
```

Where can I add this? by`@pphil23`

between `<script></script>`  before  `</body>` or

`<script src="js/file/path"></script>` as an external file before  `</body>`

Comment: Where can i add this? because with "<?php  ?>" i get an error

Comment: between <script></script> at the end of body@pphil23

Comment: if you found my answer helpful accept it, if not add more details or comment  @pphil23